# Schedule Local Notification in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to make a schedule notification app and I have followed this document : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/

The problem is notification is not showing and also no error or exception is coming.

LocalNotification.cs--- xamarin.android file

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Java.Lang;
using Test.Droid;
using Test.Models;
using Test.Views;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(LocalNotificationService))]

namespace Test.Droid
{

    public class LocalNotificationService : ILocalNotificationService
    {
        int _notificationIconId { get; set; }
        readonly DateTime _jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        internal string _randomNumber;

        public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
        {

            //long repeateDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;    
            long repeateForMinute = 60000; // In milliseconds   
            long totalMilliSeconds = (long)(notifyTime.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (totalMilliSeconds < JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
            {
                totalMilliSeconds = totalMilliSeconds + repeateForMinute;
            }

            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var localNotification = new LocalNotification();
            localNotification.Title = title;
            localNotification.Body = body;
            localNotification.Id = id;
            localNotification.NotifyTime = notifyTime;

            if (_notificationIconId != 0)
            {
                localNotification.IconId = _notificationIconId;
            }
            else
            {
                localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.icon;
            }

            var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
            intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

            Random generator = new Random();
            _randomNumber = generator.Next(100000, 999999).ToString("D6");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, repeateForMinute, pendingIntent);
        }

        public void Cancel(int id)
        {

            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Cancel(id);
        }

        public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
        {

            var packageName = Application.Context.PackageName;
            return Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        }


        private Intent CreateIntent(int id)
        {

            return new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler))
                .SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
        }

        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {

            var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            return alarmManager;
        }

        private string SerializeNotification(LocalNotification notification)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(notification.GetType());

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, notification);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
    public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";

        [Obsolete]
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
            var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);
            //Generating notification    
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
                .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
                .SetContentText(notification.Body)
                .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
                .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone))
                .SetAutoCancel(true);

            var resultIntent = LocalNotificationService.GetLauncherActivity();
            resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            var stackBuilder = AndroidX.Core.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);

            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            var resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(randomNumber, (int)PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            // Sending notification    
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.Notify(randomNumber, builder.Build());
        }

        private LocalNotification DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocalNotification));
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
            {
                var notification = (LocalNotification)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                return notification;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LocalNotification.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Views.LocalNotificationPage"
             BackgroundColor="#533F95">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="25,40,25,30" RowSpacing="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Notifications ON/OFF" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding NotificationONOFF}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="SET TIME" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="15" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <TimePicker HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Time="{Binding SelectedTime}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Format="t"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="SET DATE" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    <DatePicker HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Date="{Binding SelectedDate}" TextColor="White"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Format="MM-dd-yyyy"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="10">
                    <Label Text="Enter Message" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Editor HeightRequest="120" Text="{Binding MessageText}" TextColor="Purple" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" FontSize="15" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Purple"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderRadius="15"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

LocalNotification.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test.Views
{
   
    public partial class LocalNotificationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LocalNotificationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LocalNotificationPageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

LocalNotificationviewmode.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test.Views
{
    public class LocalNotificationPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Command _saveCommand;
        public Command SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _saveCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _saveCommand, value);
            }
        }
        bool _notificationONOFF;
        public bool NotificationONOFF
        {
            get
            {
                return _notificationONOFF;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _notificationONOFF, value);
                Switch_Toggled();
            }
        }
        void Switch_Toggled()
        {
            if (NotificationONOFF == false)
            {
                MessageText = string.Empty;
                SelectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
                DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
            }
        }
        DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedDate;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedDate, value);
            }
        }
        TimeSpan _selectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        public TimeSpan SelectedTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTime;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedTime, value);
            }
        }
        string _messageText;
        public string MessageText
        {
            get
            {
                return _messageText;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _messageText, value);
            }
        }
        public LocalNotificationPageViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new Command(() => SaveLocalNotification());
        }
        void SaveLocalNotification()
        {
            if (NotificationONOFF == true)
            {
                var date = (SelectedDate.Date.Month.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Day.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Year.ToString());
                var time = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm");
                var dateTime = date + " " + time;
                var selectedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MessageText))
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
                    DependencyService.Get <ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Local Notification", MessageText, 0, selectedDateTime);
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Notification details saved successfully ", "Ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Please enter meassage", "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Please switch on notification", "OK");
            }
        }
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;
            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;
            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Ilocalnotificationservice.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test.Views
{
    public interface ILocalNotificationService
    {
        void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime);
        void Cancel(int id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested the code you provided, and the situation you described happened. It should be caused by the elimination of `ScheduledAlarmHandler.OnReceive`. You could try to use [Local notifications in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications).

Comment: ok thank you for responding..........actually I want to schedule notification, where I can set the date , time and notification text ....please let me know how to do it or if there is any other link that can help......thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to `schedule notification, where I can set the date, time and notification text` and keep the previous style (LocalNotificationPage.xaml and LocalNotificationviewmode.cs). Only need to replace the DependencyService.

I built a new project. The only difference from yours is that I used the [official Local notifications DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications). And then remove the previous DependencyService in LocalNotificationviewmode.cs:

```
        ...
        void Switch_Toggled()
        {
            if (NotificationONOFF == false)
            {
                MessageText = string.Empty;
                SelectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
                //DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
            }
        }
        ...
        void SaveLocalNotification()
        {
            if (NotificationONOFF == true)
            {
               ...

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MessageText))
                {
                    //DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
                    //DependencyService.Get <ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Local Notification", MessageText, 0, selectedDateTime);

                    //use new DependencyService from official doc
                    DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().SendNotification("Local Notification", MessageText, selectedDateTime);
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Notification details saved successfully ", "Ok");
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
```